# How to add two buttons in ajax modelpopup in asp.net?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Here I am using two buttons, one save and other close.

when I click save button its not firing the event but popup window is appearing. 

please tell me how to do that?

```
cc1:modalpopupextender ID="mp1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panl1" TargetControlID="btnnewcategory"  BehaviorID="btnsave"
    CancelControlID="btnclose" BackgroundCssClass="Background"
cc1:modalpopupextender
```

Comment: Do you want to fire the code behind function and as well as show the popup when clicking save?

Comment: yes when i click save button it should not close the window but if i click close button that time it should close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..Add a button which is hidden..

```
<asp:Button ID="btnShowPopup" runat="server"  style="display:none" />
```

Add modal popupextender..

```
 <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="brandaddpopup" runat="server" DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="btnShowPopup" CancelControlID="btnclose" Drag="true" PopupControlID="Panl1" >
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

In **code behind:**

```
 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     //Saving Process goes here
     this.mp1.Show();
 }
```

Comment: save button is fireing correctly but when i click save button it will store data in db and popup will close but i dont want to close popup untill i click close button

Comment: ya its coming but is it possible to show window constantly i mean when i click save button again it will blink the screen instade of that its show cocstantly?

Comment: Sorry friend,You are firing a server event.So there must definitely have a postback and the postback causes the blinking..You can set style="display:none" to the panel acting as popupcontrolID to avoid blinking up to an extend,Regards..

Comment: i have one more questiopn on db can i ask?

Comment: k see in one table cat_id is there that is identity column when u insert record automatically it generating row k.for example i have enterde 10 record if i deleted 5 record den in that table only 5 records remaing k.again i insert new row but it should take 6 as cat_id but its take 11, is it possible to add row like cat_id 6

Comment: It is the case of identity rows..Instead of that i use this method..DECLARE @ID AS INT
        SELECT @ID= ISNULL(MAX(ID),0) FROM TableName 
        Select @ID=@ID+1

Comment: I use this inside the insert query and insert @ID in to the ID field..In this case you have remove the identity property..

Comment: not that in identity column there is serial like 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc if i delete 2 rows den records 1,2,3,4 k when i insert next record the id should take 5 right but it will take 7